# insert something in front of and in end of some word

Tags: vim, editor, text-editor, atom-editor

I have many many source code files, and have to do many same work like this

1. find some phrase(totally random, have to be done by human eyes)

   for example `asdf` in this line `printf("asdf")`
   and `fdsa asdf asdf` in this line `"* fdsa asdf asdf |"`
2. insert `${'` in front of the phrase, and `'}` in end of the phrase

   so `printf("asdf")` becomes `printf("${'asdf'}")`

I'm currently using vim to do the edit, is there any plugin can let me, for example, move the cursor onto `asdf` and press `ctrl+shift+i` to automatically insert `${'` and `'}` ?

Also I'm open to switch to any other editor which has such capability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a plugin for that. A simple mapping would be enough:

```
xnoremap <key> c${'<C-r>"'}<Esc>
```

See `:h key-notation` for `<key>`.

Answer (score 4):

The `:substitute` command would have been a great solution as well:

```
:%s/asdf/${&}/g
```

And if you want to *confirm* each replacement before doing it, add the `c` flag -> `%s/asdf/${&}/gc`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the great answers using built-in commands, there's one "famous" plugin for this purpose: the [surround plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697). It comes with many mappings for common stuff, and also is customizable.

To define a `ysv` (*you surround variable*) mapping, just put the following into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
let g:surround_118 = "${\r}"
```

<sup>(`118` is the code point for `v`, see :`help surround`)</sup>

Comment: Use curly-braces-names you can make this easier to maintain than remember code points. e.g. `let g:surround_{char2nr('v')} = "$(\r)"`. See `:h curly-braces-names`. You can also see an example in `:h surround-customizing`.